# is it usefull and possible and how to to change the logic of CSRF token in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

plz read the question  like 'programming and' logic

I need a 'bit higher security' than user session (than as usual).

I have a (i think) good solution for handling a 'reasonable' number of 'grace tokens'
(like saved links, communication probs, relogin and so on)

What I want to know is, how is this CSRF in rails built, can I influence it, and if, how? (the only thing I found was 'how to use in ajax, not to reuse, how to implement static ...)

*I have a good idea how to do, but I do not want to be of course with my solution.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSRF tokens are generated for each session uniquely upon each new session.

They come from:

```
protect_from_forgery
protect_from_forgery secret: "123456789012345678901234567890..."
```

Do you want to implement static CSRF token, no. Just implement your own db back security token, don't f with Rails internals. but writing your own, understand your problem and write safe code.

You could ignore completely as suggested by the Rails Security Guide

```
"a security token in non-GET requests will protect your application from CSRF"
```

Comment: sounds a bit sarcastic, but i like that, i take that as an answer.